# Windows scripting for loop

Tags: windows, scripting, batch-file

I'm new to Windows scripting. I wrote a small batch file to move subdirectories and files around in a large directory.

```
@ECHO OFF
for /f %x in ('dir /ad /b') do move %xipad %x\
for /f %x in ('dir /ad /b') do md %x\thumbs
for /f %x in ('dir /ad /b') do move %x\*thumb.png %x\thumbs\
for /f %x in ('dir /ad /b') do move %x\*thumb.jpg %x\thumbs\
for /f %x in ('dir /ad /b') do del %x\%xipad\*thumb.png
for /f %x in ('dir /ad /b') do del %x\%xipad\*thumb.jpg
for /f %x in ('dir /ad /b') do del %x\xml.php
for /f %x in ('dir /ad /b') do del %x\%xipad\xml.php
```

It looks like I can put all of my commands into a single "for /f %x in..." loop and then do the logic inside. I should probably check if the extension is .png or .jpg (not with two separate commands). What's the best way to do these two actions? In addition is there something else I should implement to make this better?

Comment: If you're open to PowerShell and you can give me a plain english explanation of what you're trying to do I'd give you a sample.  If you're learning a new scripting language for Windows that's definitely the way to go.

Comment: @ChrisN pastie.org/private/ke5pc66pl2kzsfsa0tldg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell looks a little more verbose in this instance, but here's an example anyway.  Again, as I mentioned in my comment - if you're trying to learn a scripting language for Windows right now, do yourself a favor and learn PowerShell!

```
#Get the directories we're going to work with:
Get-ChildItem -Path d:\rootdirectory\ | ? {$_.PSIsContainer} | % {
    #Remove all xml.php files from current directory and current directory ipad.
    Remove-Item ($_.FullName + "\xml.php")
    #For all the files in the directory move the each "ipad" directory into the directory with the same name.
    If ($_.Name -like *ipad) {  
        #Delete all  png and jpg images with "thumb" in the name from each current directories ipad directory
        Get-ChildItem $_ -filter "*thumb* | ? {($_.Extension -eq "jpg") -or ($_.Extension -eq "png")} | % {
            Remove-Item $_
        }
        #...Then actually move the item
        Move-Item $_ -Destination $_.FullName.Replace("ipad","")}
    }
    #Use else to work on the remainder of the directories:
    else {
        #Create a directory called "thumbs" inside all of the current directories
        $thumbDir = New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path ($_.FullName + "\thumbs\")
        #Move all png and jpg files in the current directory with "thumb" in the name into the "thumbs" directory.
        Get-ChildItem $_ -filter "*thumb* | ? {($_.Extension -eq "jpg") -or ($_.Extension -eq "png")} | % {
            Move-Item $_ -Destination $thumbDir.FullName
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do a single `for` loop the following way:

```
for /D %%x in (*) do (
  move %%xipad %%x\
  md %%x\thumbs
  move %%x\*thumb.png %x\thumbs\
  move %%x\*thumb.jpg %x\thumbs\
  del %%x\%%xipad\*thumb.png
  del %%x\%%xipad\*thumb.jpg
  del %%x\xml.php
  del %%x\%%xipad\xml.php
)
```

Note that you must use a double-`%` in batch files for those variables. And as you notice you don't need to loop over `dir` output because `for` can iterate over files and directories on its own just fine.

As for checking the extension I'm a little at a loss *what* extension you want to check, specifically. You're iterating over folders but extensions on folders rarely have any significance.

Comment: Hm, well I guess I was doing it wrong as far as extensions go (although my script did work). The extensions I am checking for are on files not directories.

Comment: When I run your version of the script it appends ipad to every directory before trying to do any of the actions.